# How to replace the nth element of multi dimension lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
a = [['0', '0'], ['0', '0'], ['0', '0']]
```

I am trying to write a function which takes nth list element as the argument and replace the 0 with 'X'. For example:
function `replace([1, 2])` would do:

```
 a = [['0', 'X'], ['X', '0'], ['0', '0']]
```

in other words, replace function should treat a as a continuous list.

Since every list is a single element I don't think it's possible. Is this possible?

Comment: Your example makes to sense, what semantics should `replace` have? Why should the result look like it does?

Comment: Your update really does not help. What is the connection between `[1,2]` and the updated `a`?

Comment: [1, 2] means the elements of the list that should be replaced. The element 1 has to be replaced by 'X' and element 2 has to be replace by '2'

Comment: But there is no `'X'` in your example output.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated  my question.

Comment: what is the output of replace([1,2,4])?

Comment: a = [['0', 'X'], ['X', '0'], ['X', '0']]

Comment: http://catherinetenajeros.blogspot.com/2013/03/password-reset.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
a = [['0', '0'], ['0', '0'], ['0', '0']]
```

You can flatten the list:

```
>>> [e for sub in a for e in sub]
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Then the elements map linearly:

```
>>> fl=[e for sub in a for e in sub]
>>> fl[1]=1
>>> fl[2]=2
>>> fl
['0', 1, 2, '0', '0', '0']
```

You can use slice assignment if you flatten the list:

```
>>> fl[1:2]='XX'
>>> fl
['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Then regroup the subgroups if you so choose:

```
>>> [list(e) for e in zip(*[fl[i::2] for i in range(2)])]
[['0', 'X'], ['X', '0'], ['0', '0']]
```

You can also translate to multidimensional subscripts:

```
li=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[7,8,9,10]]

def xlate(li,wanted):
    idx=0
    for i,e in enumerate(li):
        for j,e_ in enumerate(e):
            if idx==wanted: return (i,j)
            idx+=1


    return (None,None)        

t=xlate(li,5)
li[t[0]][t[1]]='X'
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], ['X'], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. But please see my sample output in updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Your `replace()` function makes no sense, but it's certainly possible and indeed trivial to replace anything you want in any list you want.

```
>>> a = [['0', '0'], ['0', '0'], ['0', '0']]
>>> a[0][1] = '1'
>>> a[1][0] = '2'
>>> a
[['0', '1'], ['2', '0'], ['0', '0']]
>>>
```

Comment: I know it can be done this way. I want to make a function which take element argument and perform this task.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but what is an "element argument"? Once again, your `replace([1,2])` makes no sense--why should it produce the output that you say it should? What possible connection could there be between `[1,2]` and the changes to `a`?

Comment: [1, 2] means the elements of the list that should be replaced. The element 1 has to be replaced by 'X' and element 2 has to be replace by '2'. See my updated question

Answer (score 2):

```
import math
def replace(a, t):
    for i in t:
        a[int(math.floor(i/2))][i % 2] = "X"

    return a

replace([['0', '0'], ['0', '0'], ['0', '0']], [1,2])
>> [['0', 'X'], ['X', '0'], ['0', '0']]
```

Comment: You can remove the `if` conditional by using `a[int(math.floor(i/2))][i % 2]`. This code requires that `a` consist of two-element sequences exactly.